# XML Schema for collection or array containing basic parameters along with other collections or arrays

Tags: java, xml, arrays, jaxb

I need to write an XML Schema that will allow for the production of an XML file that needs to be in a very specific format.  My hope is to use and XML Schema along with JAXB to create a data object, write to the data object, and then marshal that data object into the correctly formed XML.

Unfortunately, there does not exist a schema for this XML document, which is being read by some legacy code in a very manual way. So the goal is to create an XML Schema that will allow JAXB to marshal in this very specific way.

I am having a problem specifically with named collections or arrays.  I have a few variation on this and the most complicated version is below.

Note that I have no control over the target desired format of the XML, so I need to discover how to dictate the schema so as to produce this.  Any and all suggestions would be very, very helpful and I promise, XML Schema experts, if anyone helps me then they will be my absolute favorite person of the week!

Here is what the target format is this:

```
 <BetaInfo name="Beta ID" value="1">
      <SimpleBetaInfo>
         <Param name="Simple Beta A" value="Beta ID 1, Param A data"/>
         <Param name="Simple Beta B" value="Beta ID 1, Param B data"/>
      </SimpleBetaInfo>
      <ListBetaInfo name="List ID" value="1">
         <Param name="Item 1" value="Beta ID 1, List Index 1, Item 1 data"/>
         <Param name="Item 2" value="Beta ID 1, List Index 1, Item 2 data"/>
      </ListBetaInfo>
      <ListBetaInfo name="List ID" value="2">
         <Param name="Item 1" value="Beta ID 1, List Index 2, Item 1 data"/>
         <Param name="Item 2" value="Beta ID 1, List Index 2, Item 2 data"/>
      </ListBetaInfo>
 </BetaInfo>
```

Comment: Do the contents of the attributes have restrictions as well? For example, is there a max or min length, regexp? What are the types they support?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a starting point. It describes the structure of the instance you provided, and you can adjust it to support occurrences of child elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"> 

    <xs:attributeGroup name="commonAttributes">
        <xs:attribute name="name"  type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:attribute name="value" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:attributeGroup>

    <xs:element name="BetaInfo">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="SimpleBetaInfo" type="BetaInfoType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                <xs:element name="ListBetaInfo"   type="BetaInfoType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"/>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:complexType name="BetaInfoType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Param" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="2">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"/>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attributeGroup ref="commonAttributes"/>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

The above schema does not, however, restrict the structure of the contents of the attributes which could be done using regular expressions, nor relationships between the data in different fields (which would require XSD 1.1 which is not currently supported in JAXB).